# How to set view path for rendering email templates?

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, emails

Trying to send an email

```
Craft::$app->setViewPath('/Users/stian/dev/site.com/templates/');
Craft::$app->mailer->compose('confirmation.twig', ['orderId' => $orderId, 'customerId' => $customerId])
    ->setFrom('me@me.com')
    ->setTo('me@me.com')
    ->setSubject('hey')
    ->send();
```

Getting `The view file does not exist: /Users/stian/dev/site.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/mail/confirmation.twig`

Assuming I correctly understand how to render a view for sending as an email, how can I correctly point to its location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone struggling with this, apparently this is one way of doing it.

I struggled with this for quite some time before posting my original question, but regardless, sorry about that.

Anyway, here it is.

```
Craft::$app->setViewPath('/path/to/templates/');
$body = Craft::$app->getView()->renderTemplate('confirmation.twig', ['orderId' => $orderId, 'customerId' => $customerId]);
Craft::$app->mailer->compose()
    ->setFrom(['me@me.com')
    ->setTo('me@me.com')
    ->setSubject('hey')
    ->setHtmlBody($body)
    ->send();
```

Edit:

There's probably a better way of doing this, but if you're working in multiple environments, you can do this in `general.php`

```
'dev' => [
    'templatePath' => '/Users/stian/dev/site.com/templates/',
],
'staging' => [
    'templatePath' => '/Users/stian/dev/site.com/templates/',
],
etc
```

and then `Craft::$app->setViewPath(Craft::$app->config->general->templatePath)` in your plugin/module.

PS! Will mark as answered once I'm allowed